# Returning newly created list with 1 element inside function

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket, pascals-triangle

I'm currently working on building a function that returns a row of Pascal's triangle. My function passes in a list that contains a row in Pascal's triangle and returns the next row depending on which row was passed in.
ex. pass in '(1 2 1) and it should return '(1 3 3 1).
However I cannot seem to get the beginning 1 in the list.

```
(define build-next
   (lambda(thisRow)
      (cond
         [(null? thisRow) '(1)]
         [(null? (cdr thisRow)) (cons 1 (cdr thisRow))]
         [else (cons (+ (car thisRow) (car (cdr thisRow))) (build-next(cdr thisRow)))])))

(build-next '(1 2 1))
```

Running this code will give me the output

```
'(3 3 1)
```

without the leading 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions works if the input row has a zero as first element.
Renaming your original function to `build-next-helper` and introducing
a new `build-next` that simply calls your existing function after prefixing a zero works fine:

```
(define build-next-helper
  (lambda (thisRow)
    (cond
      [(null? thisRow)      '(1)]
      [(null? (cdr thisRow)) (cons 1 (cdr thisRow))]
      [else                  (cons (+ (car thisRow) (car (cdr thisRow)))
                                   (build-next-helper (cdr thisRow)))])))

(define (build-next thisRow)
  (build-next-helper (cons 0 thisRow)))

(build-next '(1 2 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
(define build-next
  (lambda(thisRow)
    (define helper-build-next
      (lambda (lst prev)
        (if (null? lst)
            (list prev)
            (cons (+ prev (car lst)) (helper-build-next (cdr lst) (car lst))))))
    (if (null? thisRow)
        (list 1)
        (cons (car thisRow) (helper-build-next (cdr thisRow) (car thisRow))))))
```

The recursion is performed through a helper function, that gets the rest of the row and the previous element of the row. Initially the function checks if the parameter is the empty list, so that the first row of the triangle is returned. Otherwise, the helper function is called with the initial parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a named [`let`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._let%29%29) to write `build-next` as follows:

```
(define (build-next row)
  (let loop ([row row]
             [acc 0])
    (cond
      [(zero? acc)
       (cons 1 (loop row (add1 acc)))]
      [(null? row) empty]
      [(null? (cdr row)) (list 1)]
      [else
       (cons (+ (car row) (cadr row))
             (loop (cdr row) acc))])))
```

The loop parameter *acc* is used as an accumulator to add the leading 1 in the next row (ie. first cond case).

For example,

```
(build-next '())                 ;;=> '(1)
(build-next '(1))                ;;=> '(1 1)
(build-next '(1 1))              ;;=> '(1 2 1)
(build-next '(1 2 1))            ;;=> '(1 3 3 1)
(build-next '(1 3 3 1))          ;;=> '(1 4 6 4 1)
(build-next '(1 4 6 4 1))        ;;=> '(1 5 10 10 5 1)
```